# 2.90.1 Vertices Keep Hiding, Unable to Weight Paint Mask

Tags: mesh, vertices, weight-painting, masking

I have an issue with only a part of my mesh hiding the vertices, even though it will still show the faces and the complete mesh.

It will look like this until I press Alt + H to unhide the hidden verts of the coat. The sleeves are always visible, and the coat isn't for some odd reason.

[image: Only verts for the sleeves are visible.]

After unhiding them, I proceed to go into weight painting mode and that works fine. Until I try to mask a part of the mesh and then the issue with the vertices occurs. They go back to being hidden, like I never unhid them.

[image: Alt + H to unhide the coat verts that keep hiding.]

Only the sleeves can be weight painted while in the masking mode.

[image: Verts go back to being hidden, making it hard to mask weight paint the parts I want. Only sleeves work.]

I have zero clue as to why this keeps happening.

The coat was originally a cloth simulation and converted to mesh after the simulation got to a point I liked.

Answer (score 1):

After going into sculpting mode and pressing Alt + H, it seems to have fixed the issue.

I did this because sculpt and weight paint had the same issue. Wouldn't let me touch the coat. I could sculpt and paint the sleeves, but only the sleeves.

It works now after that. I don't know why that fixed it, but it did.
For now.